# How can you catch the return of 0 in a Swift if statement?

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, seeding

I have an `init` call that either lazy loads my seed data, or loads data that exists in my database :

```
    if let savedPages = loadPages() {
        pages += savedPages
    } else {
        createPages()
    }
```

my `createPages()` method is not being called because `loadPages()` is at the very least returning `0 Results`.

```
func loadPages() -> [NSManagedObject]? {

    // Load all those pages!
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Page")
    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        return results as? [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

How can I make my `else statement` catch so that `createPages()` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

Add a return in `loadPages()`

`if results.count == 0 { return nil }`

```
func loadPages() -> [NSManagedObject]? {

    // Load all those pages!
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Page")
    do {
        let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        ///
        if results.count == 0 { return nil }
        ///
        return results as? [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Option 2:

Add `where` after `if let`

```
if let savedPages = loadPages() where savedPages.count > 0 {
    pages += savedPages
} else {
    createPages()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `where` clause:

```
if let savedPages = loadPages() where savedPages.count > 0 {
    pages += savedPages
}
else {
    createPages()
}
```